# Evaluating arithemetic expression in C with operator stored in character variable

Tags: c

I have one basic question with arithemetic operations in C language. Is it possible to somehow evaluate result in printf statement based on the operator value stored in character variable.

Example :

In the below case, I want to perform the arithemetic operations on `x` and `y` based on the value of char `op`

```
int x = 3, y =5;
char op = '+';
```

One way to solve this could be using `if/else` or `switch` statements

```
if (op == '+')
   result = x + y;
```

Is there any better way to solve it, i.e something like below (it is invalid but is there any built in function or any other way to evaluate the results)

```
int result = x op y;
```

Comment: In a word, "No." Use a switch statement.

Comment: Operators can not be defined in C.

Comment: There is no "eval" in a compiled language like C, so you need to manually identify and implement the operators.  A `switch` statement is the obvious choice for this.

Comment: You could do `op_plus(x,y)`, `op_minus(x,y)`, etc. Then you could use pointers to the functions `op_plus` etc., in a lookup table where the operator name (+,-...) links the name to the function pointer. Using a simple switch is easier, but function pointers will be, I submit, more general and extensible, should that be important.